# How to automatically read the mathpass license file in a selected time interval

Tags: licensing

I use Mathematica both at home and at work. For this, I have a Home User License, and I adapted the mathpass file, by adding my work's license server on a line before my home license in that file. So whenever Mathematica starts, it will use the first available license: hence when at work it uses the license server and when at home it uses my home license (as it should be).

I know that the license server is pinged every few minutes, so when I'm back home it quickly switches to my home license. Perfect. But the opposite is not true: it seems that from the moment it is using my home license it doesn't check the mathpass file anymore until Mathematica quits..

That is unfortunate, because when I go from home to work, it will remain on my home license instead of moving to the work license server (though it should do that for licensing reasons obviously). The only way to force a re-read of the mathpass file seems to be a restart of Mathematica. Though in general I want to avoid that, mainly because of a lot of calculation results being in memory and I don't want to lose time rerunning them. Plus, there is the issue of having to remember to restart Mathematica every time I arrive at work.

Hence my question: Is there a setting somewhere in Mathematica to force the re-read of the mathpass file at a fixed time interval (say every ten minutes or so) even when on a home license?

Comment: Although somebody here might have an answer, consider asking Wolfram Support as well: they are better positioned to answer licensing questions.